# Memory limit exceeded while deploying my ML model on GCP

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, deployment, postman

When I deploy my model, and I send a HTTP request via postman, I receive the following output on the `logs` section

```
{
insertId: "64c8f6a600074596cc54a791"
labels: {2}
logName: "projects/adenocarcinoma-detection/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-08-01T12:12:22.781032783Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Memory limit of 512 MiB exceeded with 589 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory"
timestamp: "2023-08-01T12:12:22.476566Z"
trace: "projects/adenocarcinoma-detection/traces/7c7c98b0d638caa0a4eaadd9a356ffa5"
}
```

where can I reduce the memory I am using? Maybe deleting some files?

When I run the postman request it says:
`Service Unavailable`

Comment: Increase the memory size of the Cloud Function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the amount of memory for your cloud function.

You can do this via gcloud CLI or on the console. See [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory#set-memory-limit) for how to do so